# Set location of PHP error message on page

Tags: php, forms

I am creating a log on and registration system. When validating the forms an error message is sent to the relevant page via this code -

```
echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
    foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

     echo ' <li>'.$values.'</li>';
```

The div it creates always appears at the top of the page above all my content. I've set my CSS to absolute and I can control the box. However, I don't want it absolute.
I'd like to tell the error message exactly which div to fill on the page. I've tried creating a div with the class .errormsgbox but it ignores it and creates it's own.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are closing the div? Make sure you have `echo '</div>'` after the foreach loop (or whenever you are done filling the div with content).

Comment: Hi, sorry, I had missed out some code above. The div is definitely already closed. It just keeps going into a new div at the top of the page every time...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The message was appearing whereever my PHP include was for the posted file. Moved it and now all good. Hooray.